# How to fix bad quality sound (Bang & olufsen) on HP envy 13

Tags: drivers, sound, hp

I have a problem with low quality speaker sound on my Hp envy 13 when I run Ubuntu, but on Windows it works fine.

I did some research but can't find anything useful.

Can someone help?

Comment: What is "low quality sound"? low volume? distorted?

Comment: It's a well known problem where rear speaker amplifier is powered off. I'll see if I can dig up the link and post it. Here's the first link I found for headphones: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Here's another question I found that is unfortunately unanswered so far: https://askubuntu.com/questions/952188/subwoofer-and-bangolufsen-speakers-not-working-in-hp-envy-14-j107tx

Comment: Finally here is a `reddit` thread with lots of links inside. Researching all these links should keep you out of trouble for awhile: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/

Comment: By low quality sound I mean that there is no bass and low volume. But on headphones it works fine.